# php session id: (another) strange behavior

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web-services, session

There are lot of "*strange session behavior*" items on stackoverflow.com ...

But I can't find a working solution for this problem.

This is my log:

> *index loaded* | e0540f7gad83e4fbe89710ta57e0c12 | 2014-10-18 **16:18**:10
>
> *index loaded* | e0540f7gad83e4fbe89710ta57e0c12 | 2014-10-18 **17:14**:51
>
> *webservice called* | **e183ef443dr39aa6bc265a233d66c104** | 2014-10-18 **17:21**:36
>
> *index-loaded* fires when the index.php is loaded (at the top of the script, after some includes).
>
> *webservice called* fires when the user click the submit button and the ajax js script calls the webservice (webservice.php).

In both index.php and webservice.php I have session_start() and then md5(session_id).

As you can see, the uses access index.php at **16.18** withthe first time and refreshed the page at **17.14**. After refresh, the session id is not changed (e0540f7gad83e4fbe89710ta57e0c12)
But when the user tries to submit the request to webservice.php, we have another session_id (e183ef443dr39aa6bc265a233d66c104)

Why it happens?

Comment: when you call webservice two times is there the same session_id?

Comment: Thank you Sean, Now I've tried what you suggest and the session_id is the same.

Comment: So, you have the same session_id in "index loaded" and "webservice called" log, or in both "webservice called" log occurs one by one?

Comment: In both index/webservice. I've tried to reload the index page too, in order to see if the ID would change, but it is the same for me and for many other users. For some users I have this problem. thank you

Comment: how do you recognize in that logs your and another users calls? I can't belive that there is the same session_id for many users, so, can you any unique information (maybe ip+browser?) to your logs?

Comment: I can see that every single user has the same session_id in him browser session, but every session_id are different by users (every user has a unique session_id).

Comment: hmm, how do you check `browser session_id`?

Comment: First I use session_start(); then I do this way md5(session_id()). This is the architecture: index.php (the form) webservice.php (the one who makes the insert into mysql) and UploadHandler.php (this plugin http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). When the index.php is loaded, I put in session a random code; this random code is used by webservice.php and UploadHandler.php to recognize the user: if(isset(my random code)) "it's all ok" }else{ I force the user to reload the page.

Comment: I guess index.php and UploaderHandler.php use the same session_id because another user was able to load the page, upload the file to UploaderHandler.php and when he submit the request to webservice.php (30 seconds after the last upload), the webservice.php use another session_id and can't read the session value.

Comment: All mentioned files should use the same session_id and it is default behaviour. If you have another session_id in webservice.php it means that you regenerate this id

Comment: You mean I have some session_regenerate_id() somewhere in the code?